# Converting a variable with text to a variable with numbers

Tags: python-3.x

In Python 3 I'm trying to wright a little program that will encode and decode a phrase or sentence for you.
 Here comes the problem: I'm still very new to python and need some help.
I want the program to convert the phrase of letters to a stream of numbers, and multiply it with the key the user will input. Then to decode the phrase, the numbers will be divided by the key and converted back in to letters.

TL;DR
I want to change letters listed in a variable (Example: Message = hello hi) to numbers (A = 1, B = 2, etc, (8,5,12,12,15_8,9)), then be able to change it back.

This is the whole thing so far, so you can gauge my skill level a bit:

```
EorD = input('Encoding or Decoding? E/D: ')
if EorD == "E":
    Key = input('Enter a number as your key: ')
    Message = input('Enter a message to encode: ')
    Encrypt = 1
if EorD == "D":
    Key = input('Enter your key: ')
    Message = input('Enter a message to decode: ')
    Decrypt = 1
Encrypt = 0
import string
if Encrypt == 1:
    print('Now encoding...')

elif Decrypt == 1:
    print('Now decoding...')
```

A little explanation on how I should do this would be nice.
I'm doing this to learn, so please explain any solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ASCII values of characters using `ord(character_here)` which returns the ASCII code and `chr(ascii_code)` to go back to the character. - This is the ASCII table for reference - http://www.jimprice.com/ascii-0-127.gif

http://love-python.blogspot.co.uk/2008/04/convert-text-to-ascii-and-ascii-to-text.html

Comment: How would I convert multiple characters? I have everything else working, so if i can get this, then I'm done!

Comment: You could create a variable to hold your codes eg `codes=[]`
You can use a for loop such as `for character in message: codes.append(ord(character))` which will add each code for every character to your `codes` variable, storing all the codes.
Then join the result and print: `", ".join(codes)`.

A compact way to do this is using a one line for loop like suggested by Steven below: 
`', '.join(str((ord(c) - delta) * key) for c in text)`

Answer (score 1):

Leading on from what Adam suggested is some code on roughly how you could go about it. `delta = ord('A') - 1` is used to offset the ascii value so that `'A'` will start at 1. Note that `'a'` will then have a value of 33. Look at the ascii table linked by Adam for reference.

```
def encode(text, key):
    delta = ord('A') - 1
    return ', '.join(str((ord(c) - delta) * key) for c in text)

def decode(ords, key):
    delta = ord('A') - 1
    return ''.join(chr(o // key + delta) for o in ords)

def main():
    while True:
        coding = input('Encoding or Decoding? E/D: ').lower()
        if coding == "e":
            key = int(input('Enter a number as your key: '))
            text = input('Enter a message to encode: ')
            print(encode(text, key))
        elif coding == "d":
            key = int(input('Enter your key: '))
            text = map(int, input('Enter a message to decode: ').split(', '))
            print(decode(text, key))
        else:
            break
        print()
```

---

```
# Output
>>> main()
Encoding or Decoding? E/D: e
Enter a number as your key: 1
Enter a message to encode: Hello World!
8, 37, 44, 44, 47, -32, 23, 47, 50, 44, 36, -31

Encoding or Decoding? E/D: d
Enter your key: 1
Enter a message to decode: 8, 37, 44, 44, 47, -32, 23, 47, 50, 44, 36, -31
Hello World!

Encoding or Decoding? E/D: 
>>>
```

**Bonus:**

If you want you can also have a phrase as your key.

```
def conv_key(inp):
    if inp.isdigit():
        return int(inp)
    return sum(ord(c) for c in inp)
```

Then change the `int` casts to `conv_key` like so

```
key = conv_key(input('Enter a number or phrase as your key: '))
key = conv_key(input('Enter your key: '))

>>> main()
Encoding or Decoding? E/D: e
Enter a number or phrase as your key: python
Enter a message to encode: Hello World!
5392, 24938, 29656, 29656, 31678, -21568, 15502, 31678, 33700, 29656, 24264, -20894

Encoding or Decoding? E/D: d
Enter your key: python
Enter a message to decode: 5392, 24938, 29656, 29656, 31678, -21568, 15502, 31678, 33700, 29656, 24264, -20894
Hello World!
```

Comment: How would I convert multiple characters? I have everything else working, so if i can get this, then I'm done!

Comment: What do you mean convert multiple characters?

Comment: if I do: c = hello, ord(str(c)), it tells me that I cant do more than one character at a time.

Comment: Because you can't, it can only give you the ascii value for a single character. In the output shown you can see that `'Hello World!'` has been converted to `8, 37, 44, 44, 47, -32, 23, 47, 50, 44, 36, -31` where each digit is the value for a single character in the message.